# Ada programing array of records

Tags: ada

I’m new in Ada and I’m trying to create an array of records and then put some records to the array but I got error `nested array aggregate expected`. Here is my code:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;   
with Ada.Integer_Text_Io;
with Ada.unchecked_conversion;

procedure main is
  type Byte is range 0..255;
  for Byte'Size use 8;

  type Pixel is record
    R:Byte;
    G:Byte;
    B:Byte;
  end record;
  for Pixel'Size use 24;

  r1:Pixel := (1,2,5);
  r2:Pixel := (1,2,3);
  r3:Pixel := (1,2,3);

  type Image is array(Positive range <>, Positive range <>) of Pixel;
  Pragma Pack(Image);

  Left:Image(1..3, 1..1) := (r1, r2, r3);
begin
    null;
end main;
```

Comment: You're declaring `Image` as a two-dimensional array of pixels, but then assigning a single-dimensional array of pixels to it.  What do those three pixels represent?  The three pixels at the left of the top row or the top of the leftmost column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A two-dimensional array needs a two-dimensional aggregate, i.e. an aggregate where each element is also an aggregate.  For example:

```
type Integer_Matrix is array (Positive range <>, Positive range <>) of Integer;
M : Integer_Matrix (1..2, 1..2) := ( (1, 2), (3, 4) );
```

When either dimension has length 1, it needs special handling, because a single value in parentheses isn't treated as an aggregate.  A one-element aggregate needs to be written as (1=>Value) [use the actual index in place of `1` if necessary].  In your case, each row of Image has length 1.  So you aggregate will have three elements, and each element will be another aggregate of length 1.  It will need to look like this:

```
Left : Image (1..3, 1..1) := ( (1=>r1), (1=>r2), (1=>r3) );
```

Comment: That's all valid, but I'm not sure OP is actually trying to create a 3x1 image... I think there might be a larger disconnect somewhere between intent and code.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your answer. i was trying to put one row with three columns,anyway i was wondering if you know a method where we can read an image directly from memory and put it in an array, the image is a .bmp file .

Comment: "A one-element aggregate needs to be written as (1=>Value)" great tip!